# Wired connection stops working - Ubuntu Budgie 17.04

Tags: networking, internet, 17.04, ethernet

Yesterday I decided to install Ubuntu Budgie 17.04 and everything worked fine (sort of) until maybe an hour and a couple of restarts and updates later the wired connection just dropped. I am able to use wireless, but ethernet does not connect. Left it overnight and today I booted it up - wired connection worked. Restarted once - now it doesn't work again.

I'm not sure what info I should post so please tell me what and how to get it and I will. I cannot find a solution to this; tried a couple of things I found on the internet, such as changing the DNS to 8.8.8.8, but it didn't work.

EDIT:

```
 lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3; ifconfig

04:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 12)
Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1558:0230]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169
enp4s0f1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::e9ce:fcee:ceb:6dda  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    inet6 2a02:2149:822e:5900:a76:1040:8681:db02  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
    inet6 2a02:2149:822e:5900:1bd:f1d3:b1ea:81b6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
    ether 00:90:f5:ed:04:e8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 605810  bytes 767320899 (767.3 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 447846  bytes 57206595 (57.2 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 332  bytes 24622 (24.6 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 332  bytes 24622 (24.6 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp3s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 02:df:ba:2e:0a:88  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

EDIT2: The problem seems to appear after the computer reboots while still connected via cable to the internet. I tried shutting it down and removing the ethernet cable, booting up and then connecting it and the wired connection works. However, if I reboot now, it will stop working once again.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3; ifconfig` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have done as requested.

Comment: I should mention perhaps that once again after leaving the computer powered off for a couple of hours, upon turning it on again the ethernet seems to work. I am almost sure though that if I restart it again it will stop working.

Answer (score 0):

Some revisions of `RTL8111/8168/8411` are not vey well supported by kernel drivers.

You can install a driver from Realtek by running

```
sudo apt install r8168-dkms
```

You need to be connected to the internet for it.

Comment: Of course... Wireless works, thankfully, and right now, as I commented above, wired too. Also, in case this messes up the connection more, what should I do to revert it?

Comment: To revert it run `sudo apt purge r8168-dkms`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to work. I installed the driver, rebooted, and the wired connection is gone. Only wireless works now. Something seems to be happening because of the reboot...

Comment: Check the cable, etc. It must be a hardware issue.

Comment: It really isn't. Before formatting I used Kubuntu 16.04 and I never had this problem. I also installed Elementary before Budgie, which also did not have this problem. And as I said, ethernet works the first time it boots up and stops after a reboot. From what I've seen around the internet, it could be a 17.04 issue...

Comment: It's funny, my NIC is exactly what you have, and using 17.04 since the release date, never had problems with it... You [read that](https://unixblogger.com/2016/08/11/how-to-get-your-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-working-updated-guide/)?

Comment: @Redbob Well, I did install the driver as is suggested above so the link you sent me seems to be doing the same. I checked with the sudo ethtool -i command as well to check and it seems to be installed.

Comment: @Redbob I guess 90% of people are using rtl8168. I'm using it too almost on all computers.